# opengles2 screen shot

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to capture a screenshot of what is rendered onto the screen. I have tried using glreadpixels but the results were all zeros. I'm happy to know if there are any other methods of capturing the glsurfaceview as well. Thanks a lot!

The following is a code snippet I've obtained from another thread:

```
public Bitmap savePixels(int x, int y, int w, int h){
        int b[]=new int[w*(y+h)];
        int bt[]=new int[w*h];
        IntBuffer ib=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
        ib.position(0);

        GLES20.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y+h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

        for(int i=0, k=0; i<h; i++, k++)
        {//remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
        //and so, some correction need.        
                for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
                {
                        int pix=b[i*w+j];
                        int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
                        int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
                        int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
                        bt[(h-k-1)*w+j]=pix1;

                    int test = pix;
                    if (pix > 0)    
                        System.out.println(test%256 + " " + (test/256)%256 + " " + (test/256/256)%256 + " " + test/256/256/256);
                }
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Comment: What version of Android? Prior to ICS, requires root, ICS upwards has this built in, Power+Vol Up...

Comment: if you render to your own frame buffer, you should be able to just convert the frame buffer into an image that you can save (by getting the pixels from the color buffer)

Comment: Do you mean render to texture?

Comment: Is the read buffer set correctly? See glReadBuffer()